# Equivalent of MySQL SELECT DISTINCT on data stored in CSV file

Tags: php

So I have a list of records similar to the below, stored in a tab-separated file.

```
AgentID Date
HA  13-09-2012
BC  13-09-2012
DE  13-09-2012
BC  14-09-2012
AB  14-09-2012
AB  15-09-2012
HA  15-09-2012
BC  18-09-2012
BC  19-09-2012
```

I want to show the last updated date for each userID and echo this to screen. So for the above example, the output would be

```
AgentID Date
DE  13-09-2012
AB  15-09-2012
HA  15-09-2012
BC  19-09-2012
```

What is the most efficient way to do this using PHP? I am thinking I need to read the results into an array and sort the array by date - I can't figure out how to remove the array entries that I don't want.

There are multiple AgentID's in my real file and the dates go over months and will change multiple times a day (obviously inserting the AgentID and the days date). There are also additional columns which I would want to include in the output but not consider when manipulating the data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like data that should really be in a data base, then this sort of task would be trivial

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a db available for this task - it definitely would be 100 times easier with sql :)

Comment: From your example, you don't have to store all data -- just read line-by-line, use AgentID as array key like this: `$data[$row['AgentID']]=$row['Date']` and you should end up with an latest `$data`.

Comment: what about SQLite, any up-to-date php version has it embedded

Comment: I'd convert the date to a unixtime (# ms elapsed since 1970) as a way of determining the newest date for each agent. Id have an array (agentArray)- I element per agentID. Each element would contain an array of all dates for that agent(datesArray). Convert to unix-time to sort, show the newest date for each item in the agentArray. Done.